# Hair changes color with emotion and able to change sex

Tags: story-identification

Decades ago I read a book set in a school of different races of people. One was called the jiniri or some such. Their hair changed color with their emotion and they were able to change their sex...I would LOVE to find the name of this book and its author. Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like David Brin's [Uplift War](http://www.mystgalaxy.com/book/9780553279719).  The race you describe is probably the [Tymbrimi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tymbrimi).  They are generally androgynous but can enhance features to become more male or female in form.

Comment: This doesn't sound right to me. There's no school aspect to it, the Tymbrimi have distinct genders which they do not change between, and their hair does not change color with their emotions - I don't think hair color changing is mentioned at all, and generally they express emotions using psychic glyphs.